# How to limit the display of content from a database?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using the following code to display the title and body content of articles from a database. How can I make only the first 200 characters from the article's body appear as opposed to all the characters?

```
<?php

        $select = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM articles ORDER BY id DESC");
        while ($result = mysql_fetch_assoc($select))
    {
        $id     = $result['id'];
        $title  = $result['title'];
        $body   = $result['body'];

        echo "<h2><a name='$id'>" . $title . "</a></h2>";
        echo $body . "<br />";
    }

?>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
echo $body . "<br />";
```

To this:

```
echo (strlen($body) > 200) ? substr($body,0,200) : $body;
echo "<br />";
```

That utilizes the [comparison operator](https://www.php.net/ternary) (aka the ternary operator) to output only the first 200 characters if `$body` is over 200 chars in length, and the whole body otherwise.

A common technique you could use to mark a truncated block of text would be to add an ellipsis on the end of a truncated text block (three periods, or the HTML entity `&hellip;`).  This is why I usually use the comparison operator here rather than just doing a `substr($str,0,200)`, which would work for both cases, but not let you modify them separately.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't change anything, the entire length of content (which is well over 200 characters) still appears.

Comment: I am such an idiot, your solution does work. I had two pages open and I was editing the wrong one. lol

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

[`substr($body, 0, 200)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php)

Beware if you're storing markup in the database as this may chop a tag in half.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in PHP as the others have mentioned, or directly in your query as well (if you don't need all of the data on your page):

```
$select = mysql_query("SELECT id, title, SUBSTR(body, 0, 200) FROM articles ORDER BY id DESC"
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created a function called limit. Maybe it will be useful for you as well.

```
function limit($string, $limit) {
        if (strlen($string) < $limit) {
            $result = substr($string, 0, $limit);
        }
        else
            $result =  substr($string, 0, $limit) . '...';
        return $result;
    }


echo limit('Testing my function', 5);

//Output
Test...
```